# Open bottle app at startup

Tags: bottle

I want to open an app in bottles-the environment for windows apps, when startup my laptop automatically. How can i do this?
I'm new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu recently. I want to make it like window i used to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: bottle = the Python webframework?

Comment: It's the environment to run windows apps on ubuntu

Comment: Please add a link to bottle's project page to your original question to make clear with "bottle" you are talking about, as this may affect the way to autostart it.